# Sign up in php not working and redirecting to same page with blank screen

Tags: php

I am developing Login system in php.I have one file for sign up named as `signup1.php` when I put details in sign up form and click on sign up button
it show same file `signup1.php` with blank screen.

I want to redirect `myprofile.php` when signup the user.
I put this code.

```
$user->redirect('myprofile.php');
```

code from the comment:

```
<?php 
require_once 'dbconfig.php'; 
if($user->is_loggedin()!="") { 
    $user->redirect('myprofile.php'); 
} 
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
    else{
        try { 
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT name,email FROM customer WHERE email=:umail"); 
            $stmt->execute(array(':umail'=>$umail)); 
            $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            if($row['email']==$umail) { 
                $error[] = "sorry email id already taken !"; 
            } else {
                if($user->register($fname,$lname,$uname,$umail,$uphone,$upass)) { 
                    $user->redirect('myprofile.php');
                }
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Redirect function:

```
class User {
    public function redirect($url) { 
        header("Location: $url"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some example or some code, so that people can find issue?. (Better if you can provide running example)

Comment: <?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
$user->redirect('myprofile.php');
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{else{try
  {
   $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT name,email FROM customer WHERE email=:umail");
   $stmt->execute(array(':umail'=>$umail));
   $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    if($row['email']==$umail) {
    $error[] = "sorry email id already taken !";
   }
   else
   {if($user->register($fname,$lname,$uname,$umail,$uphone,$upass)) {
 $user->redirect('myprofile.php');}}}
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {echo $e->getMessage();
  }} }?>

Comment: what it has to do with pdo

Comment: Buddy people don't know what you have written in signup1.php. We only know that you use some redirect code.

Comment: use `header('Location: myprofile.php')`;

Comment: this code is of my signup1.php

Comment: Please **Edit** your question and write all codes there.

Comment: relevant would be the function `redirect()` from your user class.

Comment: where i have to use header('Location: myprofile.php');

Comment: public function redirect($url)
 {
  header("Location: $url");
 }//this is redirect function

Comment: Well, turn on errror reporting or look at the error log of your webserver (as always with blank pages). This `if(isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
    else{` is not going to work anyway

Comment: but same code is working in localhost

Comment: now am running on server.

Comment: POST http://website/pages/signup1.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: hello everybody problem is solved by changing php version.

Answer (score 1):

From the little information you provide I can see one problem. This:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
    else{
    }   
}
```

Is not going to work, it will throw this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

An if clause works like this:

```
if( $condition ) {
    // do something if $condition is TRUE
}
else{
    // do something else if $condition is FALSE
}
```

If I understood your code correctly you should just remove the `else {` line along with its corresponding closing bracket.

Common note: If you encounter the white screen of death in PHP, without any error message, error reporting is usually disabled (wich is normal in production environments). You can activate it with these lines:

```
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Alternatively you can look at the error log of your web server (if your hoster provides one, not all do).